# IE looping infinitely when using Authorize

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth, infinite-loop, authorize

I'm developing a Facebook app, and i only want to allow access to certain views if the visitor is authorized through Facebook. This should be a pretty simple task, and i thought is was, until i tried it out in IE. The following code works fine in Chrome and Safari. I want to use Forms authentication, and therefore i have set

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
```

in web.config. This will direct the visitor to the following ActionResult when entering my app:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ManagerGame2.Utilities.StaticDataContent.InitStaticData();

        var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
        oAuthClient.AppId = FacebookApplication.Current.AppId;
        oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri(redirectUrl);
        var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "state", returnUrl } });
        return Redirect(loginUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Then the user is redirected to a Facebook page, and an access token is sent back into my OAuth ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult OAuth(string code, string state)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(Request.Url, out oauthResult))
        {
            if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
                oAuthClient.AppId = FacebookApplication.Current.AppId;
                oAuthClient.AppSecret = FacebookApplication.Current.AppSecret;
                oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri(redirectUrl);
                dynamic tokenResult = oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code);
                string accessToken = tokenResult.access_token;

                DateTime expiresOn = DateTime.MaxValue;

                if (tokenResult.ContainsKey("expires"))
                {
                    DateTimeConvertor.FromUnixTime(tokenResult.expires);
                }

                FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                dynamic me = fbClient.Get("me?fields=id,name");
                long facebookID = Convert.ToInt64(me.id);


                Account acc = (from x in db.Account.OfType<Account>() where x.FaceBookID == facebookID select x).FirstOrDefault();
                if (acc == null)
                {
                    acc = CreateAccount(me);
                }
                acc.LatestLogin = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(acc).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                MemoryUserStore.CurrentAccount = acc;

                UserRoleProvider usp = new UserRoleProvider();
                usp.GetRolesForUser(acc.AccountID.ToString());
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acc.AccountID.ToString(), false);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(state))
                {
                    return Redirect(state);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Account", new { id = acc.AccountID });
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
    }
```

What i am trying to do here, is to first verify if the token i get back from the redirect is valid. If it is, then i pull some data about the visitor, like FacebookID and Name. I then match it with my database, to see if the user already exists, and if not, i create one. I also assign a role for the user in my custom Role provider, but i had the infinite loop problem before this. Then i set

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acc.AccountID.ToString(), false);
```

and i assume this is the core of keeping track of wheter a visitor is authorized or not. As far as i understand, when the visitor is trying to call a ActionResult that requires [Authorize] then the system will check for this cookie.

Well, could someone please clarify why the above code is working in Chrome/Safari, but keeps looping through Login and then OAuth infinitely in IE?

My app is using MVC 3, EF Code First and Facebook C# SDK 5.0.25

Comment: Brian - what are the settings in the web.config for the Facebook Config section? I'd start there - I have your setup on several apps and it's working fine in all IE's (7 and up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i figured out that the problem was triggered by the [Authorize] annotation, as expected. The Facebook SDK has a [CanvasAuthorize] annotation, and when i switch to using this, IE works fine and does not login forever.

Before this, i tried using cookieless authentication, but IE still didn't want to play along.

As far as i have figured out, the problem occurs because Facebook apps are inside an IFrame. This supposedly screws something up with cookies and trust. If someone knows why this is, i would appreciate to hear about it.

Also, if anyone knows how to use and maintain roles, easily, with this [CanvasAuthorize], i would be glad to know.

Comment: I have a real answer now. Turns out that IE doesn't trust cookies from within iframes. This is because of some bad handling of P3P platform. Who would have guessed...

Anyway, i fixed it by adding:


`Response.AddHeader("P3P", "CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT'");`

to the OAuth method, since this is where the cookie is written. It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems obvious but are you sure cookies aren't disabled in IE? There is an option to disable cookies in developer tools.

Comment: Yes, that is very obvious indeed. I thought of that too. Im testing in IE 8, and the cookie settings are set by automatic cookie handling. Privacy settings for internet zone is set to medium, which blocks third-party cookies that do not have a compact privacy policy, or if they save information that can used to cantact me without explicit content. I don't think this applies to my cookies, even though i have no idea how the AuthCookie is made.

Comment: Those settings seem fine, try setting the persist parameter to true where you call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acc.AccountID.ToString(), true);

Comment: I upgraded to IE 9, for the sake of it. The problem persists.